# PostgreSQL return a JSONB object with given field names

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column. Instead of returning the entire object, I'd like to just retrieve the object with some given fields.

```
SELECT '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'::JSONB -- but only fields 'b' and 'c'
```

I realize there is a way to exclude known fields:

```
SELECT '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'::JSONB - '{a}'::TEXT[]; -- => {"b": 2, "c": 3}
```

But sometimes you simply don't know what to exclude, and want to provide a positive list of what to include...

How to approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `json_build_object` :

```
select json_build_object(
        'b', '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'::JSONB ->> 'b',
        'c', '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'::JSONB ->> 'c'
    )
```

This is an other solution using `jsonb_object_agg` to group data generated by `jsonb_each`

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) as extracted_json
FROM jsonb_each('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}') WHERE key IN ('b', 'c')
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EOlJieSl)

Comment: Thank you. That does the trick. I think the current PostgreSQL API functionality does not allow for a more succinct solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an elegant approach, so I included another solution that may be more concise.